# create html drop down based on items listed on a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, menu

I have a HTML drop down menu which works fine, but it is completely static.
ie. the items within the menu are manually entered to match the links on the main header page

eg.

```
<li><a class="tab" href="http://">INTERNAL</a>
<ul>
<li><a href=http://">Internal docs</a></li>
<li><a href="http://">SQL</a></li>
<li><a href="">Downloadables</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
```

The menu is made up of the 3 links for sections which reside within the INTERNAL page.

If I add any sections to the INTERNAL page I have to manually amend my menu to reflect this, but I would like this item to be added automatically if I add a new page

Can this be done?
I hope so!

********EDIT:**

To be clearer on this issue; I have the following html:

```
<div id="category_2232" class="category">
<div class="column" id="forum_259962">
<h3 class="clearfix"><a href=""><span>Internal KB Documents</span></a></h3>
</div>
<div class="column" id="forum_20160368">
<h3 class="clearfix"><a href=""><span>Downloadable Extras</span></a></h3>
</div>
<div class="column" id="forum_20632406">
<h3 class="clearfix"><a href=""><span>SQL Scripts</span></a></h3>
</div>
</div>
```

which I use as a guide for creating my menu, which takes the form:

```
<li><a class="tab" href="http://">INTERNAL</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="http://">Internal KB Documents</a></li>
<li><a href="http://">Downloadable Extras</a></li>
<li><a href="http://">SQL Scripts</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
```

I would like to take the first code, and whenever I add a new <div>, I want a corresponding <li> entry on the menu to be updated automatically.

Please help!
Im sooo sure I could do this!
There has to be some JS somewhere that can generate menu items....

Many thanks to all involved so far
Howie

Comment: Show the HTML for the drop down menu!

Comment: that is the drop down menu. thats the bit I want to have dynamically set.

Comment: Are the divs and the menu in different pages?

Comment: Binu, yes, they are on different pages.

Answer (score 1):

When the DOM is ready, find your list items and use the text of the anchors to create option elements which you can append to the select. It will make querying the DOM much easier if you add some ID's to your markup.

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Vg8K9/)**

**jQuery**

```
$(function () {
    var select = $('#internal-select');
    var items = $('#internal-list li a').each(function () {
        var text = $(this).text();
        select.append('<option value="' + text + '">' + text + '</option>');
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<li><a class="tab" href="http://">INTERNAL</a>
    <ul id="internal-list">
        <li> <a href="http:// ">Internal docs</a></li>
        <li><a href="http:// ">SQL</a></li>
        <li><a href=" ">Downloadables</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<select id="internal-select"></select>
```

Comment: I think my explanation perhaps was a little misleading.
My example above IS the drop down menu. I want this menu to be created based upon the items found within anoter page